# Is it possible to run django migrations within a python script?

Tags: python, django, migration

I have a django application, let's call it `django_app` and I can `pip install django_app` to get it installed. But I still need to run the migrations for this app. For one reason or another, the team's required to run the migrations within a python script. Is it possible to run the migrations within the another python script if the django application is installed via a pip command?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this with `execute_from_command_line`

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'yourdjangoapp.settings'
django.setup()
django.core.management.execute_from_command_line(['manage.py', 'migrate', 'backend'])
```